# Updating a section of a page to show "News" (Without using a database) Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, placeholder

I want to have a news section to my page in a placeholder which can be updated relatively frequently with just Text and a Date.

But I do not want it to be linked to a Database, Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: So just where do you think to store the news? That's your main concern, after that you can think how to pull them and show them.

Comment: Are you asking how to get news which isn't linked to a database, or to update the placeholder, or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not prepared to use a Database, keep it as static content. Another option would be to use a simple text or xml file and read this in.

Comment: @gleno. Just curious, why would serverside XML cause issues with SEO?

Comment: Since you are using js to dynamically fetch data and rebuild your dom, there's no gurantee that the bot who crawls your page will execute your javascripts. I'm not too familiar with details, but I've heard that googles and the like might be adding some limited functionality toward this. But in the end it's all about the money. I bet it's quite expensive to execute all js out there even for a very short time. Consequently your content (in this case the newsfeed) will not be crawled proper.

Answer (score 3):

You could save the news as an RSS file (simply an XML file format suited for news) and then parse and display it in asp.net.

Here's a tutorial to get you started:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/RSSFeedEx.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [RSS feeds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS), example [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/10628494)

Answer (score 1):

If by **not linked** you mean **not bound**, yeah. Use ajax to fetch news on a specified interval and append them to your element at client-side. If you're not talking about binding, then you need a **news source** which could be:

1. An RSS feed
2. An XML document
3. A database
4. A flat text file
5. An Excel spreadsheet

and more sources, in which you have to someway write the code to fetch the information and update the UI. That's inevitable.

Comment: Jesus, an excel sheet? Really? They do that?... :)

Comment: Haven't you seen office solutions based on Excel and Access as back-end storage? yeah, they do that :D